Unable to disable drill down and drill up in a Power BI Matrix
I have a Power BI matrix visual and want to disable the drill down and drill up features (i.e, not the drill thru features).  I went to Options and turned off the option for Stepped Layout.  I also turned off the drill down and drill up features on the visual formatting tab (i.e, I turned off the 'Drill on dropdown', the 'Drill up', the 'Show next level', and the 'Expand to next level' features).  After turning all these to off I published the dashboard to the service, but the drill down and drill up features are not disabled.  Any ideas why?
I went to options and turned off the option for Stepped Layout.  I also turned off the drill down and drill up features on the visual formatting tab (i.e, I turned off the 'drill on dropdown', the drill up, the show next level, and the expand to next level features).  I published the dashboard to the service and was expecting the drill up and drill down features to be disabled, but they are not.
